# using local Maven repository in boot Clojure

Tags: maven, clojure, boot-clj

I'd like to use the local Maven repository (at `~/.m2/repository` by default) to find a dependency for a Clojure project built by [boot](http://boot-clj.com).

I am quite certain that the dependency is in the repository:

```
$ ls ~/.m2/repository/ags799/boot-docker/0.0.0-7-gd5196b9-dirty/
_maven.repositories
boot-docker-0.0.0-7-gd5196b9-dirty.jar
boot-docker-0.0.0-7-gd5196b9-dirty.pom
```

I'm quite certain that my project properly refers to the dependency. This is my `build.boot`

```
(set-env! :dependencies `[[org.clojure/clojure ~(clojure-version)]
                          [ags799/boot-docker "0.0.0-7-gd5196b9-dirty.jar"]])

(task-options!
  pom {:project 'example
       :version "0.0.0"}
  aot {:namespace #{'example.core}}
  jar {:main 'example.core})
```

However, when I run `boot repl`, I get this:

```
                                                    java.lang.Thread.run                    Thread.java:  745
                      java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run        ThreadPoolExecutor.java:  617
                       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker        ThreadPoolExecutor.java: 1142
       org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run    RunnableErrorForwarder.java:   60
org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run  WagonRepositoryConnector.java:  669
     org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap  WagonRepositoryConnector.java:  941
     org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap  WagonRepositoryConnector.java:  947
      org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact ags799:boot-docker:jar:0.0.0-7-gd5196b9-dirty.jar in clojars (https://repo.clojars.org/)
      artifact: #object[org.sonatype.aether.util.artifact.DefaultArtifact 0xa82                      java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run        ThreadPoolExecutor.java:  61to                       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker        ThreadPoolExecutor.java: 114he       org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run    RunnableErrorForwarder.java:   6rtorg.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run  WagonRepositoryConnector.java:  66ul     org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap  WagonRepositoryConnector.java:  94ot     org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap  WagonRepositoryConnector.java:  94:1      org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact ags799:boot-docker:jarlu      artifact: #object[org.sonatype.aether.util.artifact.DefaultArtifact 0xa82                      java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run        ThreadPoolExecirty.jar in clojars (https://repo.clojars.org/)
    result: #object[org.sonatype.aether.resolution.DependencyResult 0x5a37d3ed "[org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.8.0 < maven-central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2, releases+snapshots), null < null]"]
                                  clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Could not find artifact ags799:boot-docker:jar:0.0.0-7-gd5196b9-dirty.jar in clojars (https://repo.clojars.org/)
    line: 3
```

I have also tried manually setting boot's path to the local Maven repository by including `:local-repo "~/.m2/repository"` in the `set-env!` command. This does not change the output.

I have also tried replacing `~` in this path with the explicit `$HOME` path (`/Users/andrew`). This does not change the output.

This is my project's `boot.properties`:

```
BOOT_CLOJURE_NAME=org.clojure/clojure
BOOT_CLOJURE_VERSION=1.8.0
BOOT_VERSION=2.7.2
```

How can my project use the local Maven repository for finding dependencies? Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dependency declaration, should it include `.jar` at the end?

i.e. Shouldn't it be like this?

```
(set-env! :dependencies `[[org.clojure/clojure ~(clojure-version)]
                          [ags799/boot-docker "0.0.0-7-gd5196b9-dirty"]])
```

Comment: Indeed, *sigh*. The `local-repository` setting is unnecessary. This ended up being a pretty simple problem, I don't mind deleting this question.

Comment: Don't worry about it. You had an issue, chances are somebody else will too, and they might find it helpful.